# Handle duplicate value error in CRUD app (react-redux + express-mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose, react-redux

Having `mongoose` schema where `carNumber` should be unique:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  carNumber: {
    type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true},
  },
  carOwner: String
});
```

With `express` controller function data is saved into db:

```
export const addCar = (req, res) => {
  const newCar = new Car(req.body);
   newCar.save((err, car) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({ 'success': false, 'message': 'Some Error' });
    }
     return res.json({ 'success': true, 'message': 'Car '+ car.carNumber +' added successfully', car });   
  }) 
}
```

but returns `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'carNumber' of undefined` when trying to add duplicate value. To avoid error function is updated to validate `undefined` value:

```
export const addCar = (req, res) => {
  const newCar = new Car(req.body);
   newCar.save((err, car) => {
     if (car.carNumber === undefined) {
           return res.json({ 'success': false, '': 'Some Error' });
      }
    else {
        return res.json({ 'success': true, 'message': 'Car '+ car.carNumber +' added successfully', car });   
       }  
  }) 
}
```

But getting `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0` at `response.json().then(error => { ... }` in front-end redux action:

```
export const addNewCar = (car) => {
  console.log(car)
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(addNewCarRequest(car));
    return fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: 'post',
      body: car,
    }).then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then(data => {
          console.log(data.car);
          dispatch(addNewCarRequestSuccess(data.car, data.message))
        })
      }
      else {
        response.json().then(error => {
          dispatch(addNewCarRequestFailed(error))
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Feeling totally lost there... May someone was fallen into same problem?

Comment: I think you're chaining `.then()` onto your `json()` instead of onto your `fetch()`.

Comment: @Colin should I use `catch` ?

Comment: Yeah, you need to put `.then()` in the right place, and then `.catch()` to catch any errors.

Comment: @Colin you mean "right" place?

Comment: I don't understand. What?

Comment: @Colin tried to `error => {throw new Error(error)}`  `if (!response.ok)` in https://i.gyazo.com/210ef1d55f73b328b1c36ca0888b1ae9.png but getting same `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0` may you know what I am missing here?

Comment: You didn't do what I said to try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170045/discussion-between-o-o-and-colin).

Comment: Try a quick read ;)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, I think you have `.then()` on your `json()` instead of on your `fetch()`. You need something of the shape:

```
export const addNewCar = car => {
  console.log(car);
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(addNewCarRequest(car));
    return fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "post",
      body: car
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw Error('blah')
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.car);
        dispatch(addNewCarRequestSuccess(data.car, data.message));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(addNewCarRequestFailed(error));        
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Many thanks for help, after all, it brings error: https://i.gyazo.com/bb9aff25fddac33955dcd150a147f5af.png , trying to understand how to solve it, could you elaborate on it?

Comment: Seems that .catch send `undefined` value to `cars` array, now it is working but seems like workaround.